# Screen Capture, diminuir tamanho de arquivo bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi

Uma das funções do projeto que estou trabalhando faz a captura da tela do usuário, porém o arquivo bitmap esta ficando muito grande, de 6MB a 8MB, fica ruim para poder enviar via socket ou futuramente fazer uma stream por frame, alguém poderia me ajudar em como posso diminuir o tamanho deste arquivo?
vou estar postando o codigo que estou usando para capturar a screen, e depois salva-la em um arquivo..

```
    void Remote_Manip::CaptureScreen(Socket_Setup &socket_setup)
{
    int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,
        nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);
    BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight,
        hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, 0, path)))
    {
        std::wstring directory_create = path;
        std::string DEFAULT_DIR;

        DEFAULT_DIR.append(directory_create.begin(), directory_create.end());
        DEFAULT_DIR.append("\\Pictures");
        DEFAULT_DIR.append("\\image.bmp");

        LPCSTR fname = DEFAULT_DIR.c_str();
        HPALETTE hpal = NULL;
        saveBitmap(fname, hCaptureBitmap, hpal);

        ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
        DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
        DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);

        // fução para enviar a imagem via socket.
        FILE_DOWNLOAD(DEFAULT_DIR.c_str(), socket_setup);
    }
}
```

Comment: A solução clara seria salvar em formato PNG.

Comment: Um arquivo bitmap vai realmente ficar grande, proporcionalmente à resolução em que sua interface está sendo exibida, pois ele guarda os dados "crus" (*raw*) de cada pixel. Utilizar um formato com compressão, como sugerido pelo @GuilhermeBernal, pode ser interessante para diminuir esse tamanho no armazenamento.

Comment: Agora, outra questão importante que você mesmo prevê é a utilização futura. Já que você menciona a transmissão para *streaming*, é bom pensar a respeito de enviar apenas a diferença entre cada quadro (*frame*). No final, o problema vai ser o mesmo dessa outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6978/como-determinar-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-pequenas-%C3%A1reas-para-renderizar