# Como medir área e diâmetro de imagem escaneada irregular plana (não é 3D) usando java?

Tags: java, processamento-de-imagens

Sou da área da saúde e nunca fiz curso de Linguagem de Programação, mas por alguns motivos vou precisar fazer um software para ajudar em minha pesquisa.

Preciso medir a área total e também área/3 de uma imagem, já convertendo diretamente de pixel para centímetros. É possível?

E o comprimento de uma ponta da imagem a outra em cm? É possível? Como faço? Como inicio isso?

Comment: Você precisa a área de toda a imagem que será fornecida como entrada ao software ou só de uma parte da imagem? Por exemplo, você precisa reconhecer algum padrão na imagem e saber apenas a área deste padrão (como a área de determinada coloração em uma lâmina)? Talvez seja interessante você oferecer um exemplo e o resultado que espera, tornaria mais simples a sugestão de uma solução.

Comment: Ola nossa responderam tão rápido q até me assustei rsrsrs...então, a imagem é tipo quando se coloca uma tinta na mão e carimba numa folha A4 fica aquela impressão. Então segundo o que ja faco manualmente eu descarto,preciso cortar os dedos e só uso a palma da mao pra fazer as medições segundo o primeiro indice, para calcular o comprimento eu pegava a régua  e media o menor comprimento q encontrava pelo maior comprimento na horizontal de uma ponta a outra da palma da mao . fazendo essa divisão eu encontrava um valor x q eu preciso.

Comment: Não terminei...agora o segundo índice é dividir a palma da mão em 3 áreas A,B,C. E dividir a área c pela soma das 3 áreas...e nao queria fazer isso manualmente..da muito trabalho são por exemplo 800 maos... Por isso surgiu a ideia de criar esse programa

Comment: A ideia era eu escanear a folha A4 com a imagem da mao. E usar a imagem , não queria alterar o tamanho dela após o escaneamento p não perder a imagem real..

Comment: Entendi. Bom, assim que possível vou rascunhar uma resposta para te guiar, não a solução final, mas o caminho para você. com algum exemplo. Vou usar o A4 como base para a conversão de pixels para CM também. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Sim eu ja li algumas coisas a respeito dessa conta em pixel e converter p cm, em alguns artigos de imagens de odontologia, etcB.runo qual seu email ou celular vc poderia manter contato?

Comment: Débora, algum motivo em especial para se usar Java? O que você quer fazer é um tipo de tarefa muito comum, no entanto, o procedimento normal é colocar uma escala na imagem, pois mesmo escaneando a folha A4, o tamanho da imagem vai variar e o erro vai ser grande. Você pode colocar a escala no scanner sobre uma parte branca da folha. Procure também sobre o programa *ImageJ*, ele possui várias ferramentas para análise de imagens, incluindo medir distâncias e áreas. Você pode automatizar as tarrefas e ler todas imagens em poucos segundos.

Answer (score 4):

Muitos colegas já te forneceram ótimas informações via comentários. E o princípio do que eles disseram está corretíssimo: você precisa ter uma escala estabelecida com a relação entre os pixels da imagem e os centímetros de objetos no mundo real (por exemplo, cada 10 pixels na imagem correspondem a 20cm na folha A4 real). Tendo isso, basta fazer uma [regra de três simples](http://www.somatematica.com.br/fundam/regra3s.php) e você calcula o comprimento em centímetros de um objeto medido em pixels.

Como também já comentaram, há duas formas de estabelecer essa escala:

1. Calibragem do equipamento. Você monta a câmera e a base dos objetos (ou o scanner) de uma forma fixa, para que sempre sejam produzidas as mesmas fotos, isto é, com a mesma distância do objeto e a mesma resolução. Ai você tira uma foto (ou faz um scanner) e manualmente mede a escala obtida, configurando o seu programa com ela. Durante a captura das imagens seguintes, esse valor vai continuar correto contanto que você não mude os equipamentos envolvidos.
2. Calibragem automática baseada em um padrão. Sempre que obter uma imagem, você inclue junto com o objeto de interesse um outro objeto *conhecido*, com um padrão fácil de detectar via algoritmos de visão computacional (uma faixa xadrez, por exemplo). Esse objeto conhecido deve ter dimensões fixas e também conhecidas. Ao processar a imagem, você primeiro localiza tal objeto, e mede suas dimensões em pixels. Como as dimensões reais dele são conhecidas, você também usa a regra de três pra encontrar a relação (escala) da imagem. Ai, é só aplicá-la no objeto de interesse real.

Cabe notar que em processos automatizados, na a indústria, na agricultura, e talvez também em laboratórios (como parece ser o seu caso), geralmente usa-se a abordagem 1 porque é muito simples controlar o ambiente de captura da imagem (e assim não é necessário fazer processamentos adicionais de localizar o padrão a cada imagem processada).

Como já mencionado, tendo a escala basta extrair o objeto de interesse, fazer a medição em pixels e fazer o cálculo de conversão para centímetros. Você pode ter dificuldades também em como estrair o objeto de interesse, mas para isso há alguns métodos.

A limiarização (*thresholding*) é um método bem simples, que funciona bem principalmente em ambientes controlados (por exemplo, se você tem tinta preta sobre uma folha de papel branca). A ideia desse método é bem simples: você escolhe um valor de pixel para ser o limiar (*threshold* em inglês, dai o nome do método), e então vai até a imagem e altera para 0 (preto) todos os pixels com valor menor do que o limiar escolhido e pra 1 (branco) todo os pixels com valor maior do que o limiar escolhido. A imagem final vai ser uma imagem binária (só com 0 e 1) claramente delimitando o seu objeto de interesse (claro, dependendo de uma escolha apropriada do limiar e se o seu objeto de interesse é mais claro/escoro do que o fundo). Sugiro ler [esta outra pergunta do SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8578/73), que trata justamente sobre esse assunto (em outro domínio de problema, mas que lhe serve da mesma forma).

Outro método possível de utilização é o crescimento de região (*region growing*). Ele é um pouco mais complexo, mas ainda assim fácil de entender. Você "sorteia" um pixel pra ser a "semente" (o início de uma nova região). E então, vai analisando os pixels vizinhos pra ver se eles são *similares* (o critério de similaridade você escolhe: pode ser proximidade de valores, se deseja que a mesma cor seja agrupada, por exemplo). Esse processo continua com os vizinhos dos vizinhos até que acabem os pixels vizinhos ou a similaridade indique que não há mais vizinhos para serem agrupados. Essa nova região é um objeto (pode ser o de interesse, ou pode ser o fundo, por exemplo). Se sobrarem pixels na imagem ainda não processados, você sorteia uma nova semente, e começa uma nova região. Ele vai assim até processar toda a imagem. Nesta [minha resposta aqui do SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7003/73) há uma ilustração detalhada desse método em outro domínio de problema, mas que também pode te ajudar.

Depois que você separar o objeto de interesse do fundo, basta medir suas dimensões. Se você também puder controlar o ambiente de captura, facilita porque pode colocar o objeto sempre em uma posição pré-estabelecida (na horizontal, por exemplo), e então o comprimento em pixels será a quantidade de pixels na matriz da imagem contada no eixo x, e a largura será a quantidade de pixels na matriz contada no eixo y. A área, naturalmente, é a quantidade de pixels na região extraída.

> P.S.: [Este blog](http://patrick-fuller.com/images-are-data-an-introduction-to-image-processing-for-scientists-and-engineers/) contém um tutorial muito didático (embora em
>   inglês) sobre alguns princípios do processamento de imagem. Vale a
>   leitura.