# Contagem de pixels pretos que foram traçados em imagem na web

Tags: php, javascript

Quero que o usuário trace uma linha em uma imagem biométrica e que seja feita uma contagem automática de "partes pretas" da digital que esta linha atravessou.

[image: Exemplo]

Não tenho ideia de qual ferramenta usar e por onde começar... Alguém tem algum caminho?

É para ambiente web...

Comment: Se você não sabe qual tecnologia usar, é dificil obeter ajuda aqui. Pelo que vocẽ falou, da pra fazer isso usando canvas. Basta percorrer sequencialmente todos os pixels da linha e verificar quando há uma alternancia total de branco para preto.

Comment: Existem algumas abordagens que podem ser úteis, mas que vão depender da qualidade da imagem. A minha intuição diz que você deveria : 1) converter a imagem para tons de cinza (para evitar trabalhar com RGB); 2) aplicar um filtro para a extração de bordas (tem um algoritmo simples [nesta minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125339/73)); 3) segmentar a região sob a linha (ignorar todo o resto da imagem); 4) contar os **agrupamentos** de pixels pretos (como um [crescimento de região](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7003/73)).

Comment: Aliás, você tem um [mcve] em Javascript que faz a parte de exibir a imagem da digital (uma qualquer, de exemplo) e permite traçar a linha nela? Se tiver, compartilhe-o, que vai facilitar muito pra que alguém te ajude de forma mais direta/completa.

Comment: Outra coisa: isso parece ser factível em Javascript. Assim, vc consegue mostrar o resultado pro usuário sem precisar fazer requisições ao servidor. Eu tentariar por esse caminho antes de tentar em PHP.

Comment: O que você quer um um sistema de leitura biométrica? Se for, baseado em linhas, nunca será preciso, pois poderá ter repetição. A ideia não é traçar linhas mas fazer um mapeamento de pontos nas pontas dos traços e intersecções do desenho, onde tiver registro de preto. E depois capturar estes pontos novamente.

Comment: Como [nesse exemplo de imagem](http://i0.wp.com/questoesinsanas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/leitura-biom%C3%A9trica.jpg).

Comment: Tente fazer alguma coisa [com isso](https://code.google.com/archive/p/scanphp/downloads). ou [com isso](http://www.sourceafis.org/blog/) ou [com isso](https://github.com/rtshadow/biometrics)

Comment: [Aqui](https://books.google.pl/books?id=1Wpx25D8qOwC&lpg=PA120&ots=9wRY0Rosb7&dq=poincare+index+fingerprint&hl=pl&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q&f=false) tem um livro que pode te ajudar

Comment: [Relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157879/contar-pixels-pretos-de-uma-regi%C3%A3o-da-imagem/)

Comment: Mais [relacionado](https://github.com/harthur/hog-descriptor) com assunto.

Comment: E se você converter a imagem para **ASCII** e encontrar o padrão a partir da aí?

Answer (score 1):

## Explicação

Você pode utilizar o próprio php para realizar tal feitio, não precisa utilizar javascript se não quiser, fiz um exemplo manipulando e criando uma imagem de apenas duas cores que utilizei para teste (preto e branca) e modelando ela no proprio html novamente com escala de 10 pixels por 10 pixels.

## Codigo

```
<style>
    .container {
        height: 10px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .bloco {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    .preto {
        background: black;
    }
    .branco {
        background: white;
    }
</style>
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('biometria.png'); //aqui é o caminho da imagem
$IniX = 0;  //inicio largura
$FimX = 10; //dimensão de largura da imagem
$IniY = 0;  //inicio altura
$FimY = 10; //dimensão de altura da imagem
$codigoCorPreta = 0; //se for rgb(0,0,0) é zero. porém nem todo preto é realmente preto.
$pxPreto = 0; //qtd. de pixels pretos zerada inicialmente
for ($y = $IniY; $y < $FimY; $y++ ) {
    echo '<div class=container>'; //container para envolver cada linha horizontal
    for($x = $IniX; $x < $FimX; $x++ ) {
        $value = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        if ($value === $codigoCorPreta){ 
        //se a cor no pixel atual for totalmente preta vai entrar aqui mas tbm poderia ser '($value < 9000000)' por exemplo para captar mais tons de preto.
            $cor = 'preto';
            $pxPreto++; //incrementa qtd de pixels pretos
        } else {
            $cor = 'branca';
        }
        echo "<div class='bloco {$cor}'></div>"; //cria uma div de 10x10 simulando 1 pixel com a cor branca ou preta.
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
echo "Total de pixels pretos: {$pxPreto}"; //aqui imprime a quantidade total de pixels pretos que foi percorrido.
?>
```

## Resultados

Esta foi a imagem que usei como exemplo a `"biometria.png"`
[image: imagem que utilizei de exemplo]

E este foi o resultado obtido no HTML gerado pelo PHP:

[image: resultado do html gerado pelo php]

"Testes reais" em uma imagem biométrica:

Img de exemplo: [image: fingerprint]

**Neste teste utilizei `if ($value < 9000000){` para checar se "é preto ou não" 
 com o intuito de abrangir mais tons de preto e não somente `rgb(0,0,0)`**

Resultados:

[image: resultado biometria]

## Observações

O valor que utilizei de `($value < 9000000)` foi apenas pra testes, não sei te dizer se esse seria um valor "plausível" para identificar tons pretos.

Caso a imagem que você queira trabalhar seja `jpg` você deve mudar a função `imagecreatefrompng` para `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

Tirando como exemplo o projeto ImageColorPicker(https://github.com/Skarabaeus/ImageColorPicker/).

https://github.com/Skarabaeus/ImageColorPicker/blob/master/src/ImageColorPicker.js linha80

```
... .bind("mousemove", function(e){
   ...
      /*Aqui coloque sua lógica - (toda vez que q o pixel for da cor */
      /* que vc determinar incrementa um contador). */
   ...
});...
```