# Contar pixels pretos de uma região da imagem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho um script que consigo selecionar as coordenadas de uma área de uma imagem:

https://jsfiddle.net/zauk0qLk/2/

Considerando que eu tenha uma imagem `binária` (**preto** e **branco**), como faço para contar a quantidade de pixels preto em uma determinada área dessa imagem.

Por exemplo, quero saber a quantidade de pixels preto na seguinte área da imagem:

```
{"se":[175,145],"sd":[229,145],"ie":[175,221],"id":[229,221]}
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi direito suas tags. Você quer contar os pontos com PHP ou JS?

Comment: Pra mim indifere, porque só preciso do retorno da quantidade para tratar em PHP, então pode ser PHP ou JS.

Answer (score 3):

Se entendi bem, para contar somente os pixels **pretos** da área imagem, você precisa varrer cada pixel da área verificando se ele é preto ou não.
Para manipular a imagem, ela precisa estar em um canvas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

var contador = 0;
for(var i = pos.top; i < pos.bottom; i++)
    for(var j = pos.left; j < pos.right; j++){
        var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(i, j, 1, 1).data; //valor de cores do pixel i,j em RGBA 
        if(pixeldata[0] == 0 && pixeldata[1] == 0 && pixeldata[2] == 0) //R, G e B == 0
            contador++;
    }
```

PS: não testei, agradeço se puder testar e dar feedback

Comment: Tem razão, confesso que não tinha visto o exemplo no jsfiddle.

Comment: Olá amigo tudo bem! Interessante sua sugestão. Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou fazer aqui os testes e logo compartilho o resultado aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Se for fazer em php tente algo como:

```
$numeroDePixels = abs(($se[0]-$id[0])*($se[1]-$id[1]));
```

Neste código temos:

> ($se[0]-$id[0]) como largura da área.
>
> ($se[1]-$id[1]) como altura da área.
>
> Área = Largura * Altura

E usamos `asb()` para evitar que o resultado seja negativo.

Comment: Olá amigo, tudo bem? Acredito que ai iriamos contar os pixels como um todos e não filtrar para somente uma cor, no caso preto. Alguma sugestão? Obrigado pela ajuda!